# determineUser for STOMP via SockJs when using XHR Streaming

Tags: spring, grails, spring-websocket, sockjs

The client does not support WebSockets, so SockJs uses XHR Streaming and determineUser, while called when using WebSockets, does not get called at all. Is there another way to set the principal?

This is what I have:

```
class CustomHandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {
    @Override
    protected Principal determineUser(
        ServerHttpRequest request,
        WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
        Map<String, Object> attributes
    ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: were you able to figure out the answer for this one ?