# Determine user when using Xhr-streaming via SockJS

Tags: spring-boot, sockjs

I am unable to determine user when is connected through Xhr-steaming instead of websocket.
Link to similar question [determineUser for STOMP via SockJs when using XHR Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287071/determineuser-for-stomp-via-sockjs-when-using-xhr-streaming)